# Busca registro do usuário da sessão no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho um sistema de troca de seguidores, onde o usuário irar loga no painel e usar sua lista de então criei um texarea pra ele pode colocar a lista dele que e no formato email@provedor:senha e em seguida irar salvar os dados na tabela do banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e após se carregado 100% e inserido os registro no banco de dados irei chama uma pagina pra pode verificar se o login foi valido ou não no Instagram e se for valido irar alterar o valor da coluna testado ( N = Não checado , B = Login valido R = Login ruim )

o php que vai verificar se o login e bom ou e ruim  ele recebe o valor email e senha do banco de dados e vai testado até finaliza todo os registro que o usuário cadastro no texarea .

a minha duvida e como posso fazer isso sem afeta outros usuários , cada usuário só vai pode verificar a lista que for dele que irar verificar quem é pela a coluna usuario .

Obrigado...

Comment: mas se é para filtrar pelo campo usuário pq não (SELECT testados FROM tabela WHERE usuario = "<nome do usuario>")

Answer (score -1):

Você quer fazer uma verificação se a lista é boa, ruim ou se não está verificada? Não entendi muito o que você quis dizer, mas vamos lá.

Faça uma fetch_array pra pegar a string do campo "testado":

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT testados FROM tabela");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

Agora só faz um sisteminha de IF pra ver se está no valor que você quer, foi isso que eu entendi...

Comment: Já tenho funcionando sem banco de dados porem e muito lento pois ele carrega todo o registro do texarea pra fazer o check dos login do instagram , a duvida e que muitos usuários loga no painel e eles adiciona sua lista pra verificação e eu pensando que salvar no banco de dados e ir testado login por login da base até finaliza seja mais rápido . Pago pro profissional me ajuda :/